# Graphite adding new resolution to a metric

Tags: metrics, graphite, statsd

Given I have a metric (stats.counters.PROD.FailedBuildMessages) and I want to extend its resolution (stats.counters.PROD.FailedBuildMessages.1, stats.counters.PROD.FailedBuildMessages.2, stats.counters.PROD.FailedBuildMessages.3 etc') but I don't want to lose my previous data and still use it as long as I can, how can I overlay the data? It seems once I add the sub counters to the FailedBuildMessages node it loses the data.

is there a way to do it?

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by extend its resolution? (do you mean keep it for a longer time with good precision?)

Comment: Adding another level. For instance i have a counter statsd.counter.A that worked for a year, now I want to add new "depth" to the A counter such as: statsd.counter.A.X and statsd.counter.A.Y, once I added this resolution to my A counter, I lost the data A held.

Comment: by lost, do you mean the wsp file has disappeared from your filesystem or that you can't fetch it via the web interface ?

Comment: @kamaradclimber I can't fetch it via web. We decieded to leave it at that, we'll just leave the system to gather new data, overtime the gaps will be closed :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should send the old metric alongside the new one. They are completely different metrics even if they share the same hierarchy.

I do that in order to have coarser/finer details on a metric and it works quite well.